# How to get entities from a searchResults object in GAE NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm not sure if I'm using the NDB Search API as it's meant to be used. I've read through the documentation, but I think I'm either missing something or lacking in my python skills. Can anyone confirm/improve this progression of using search?

```py
# build the query object
query_options = search.QueryOptions(limit=results_per_page, offset=number_to_offset)
query_object = search.Query(query_string=escaped_param, options=query_options)

# searchResults object
video_search_results = videos.INDEX.search(query_object)

# ScoredDocuments list
video_search_docs = video_search_results.results

# doc_ids
video_ids = [x.doc_id for x in video_search_docs]

# entities
video_entities = [Video.GetById(x) for x in video_ids]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might personally write this something more like:

```
# build the query object
query_options = search.QueryOptions(limit=results_per_page, offset=number_to_offset)
query_object = search.Query(query_string=escaped_param, options=query_options)

# do the search
video_search = search.Index(name=VIDEO_INDEX).search(query_object)

# list of matching video keys
video_keys = [ndb.Key(Video, x.doc_id) for x in video_search.results]

# get video entities
video_entities = ndb.get_multi(video_keys)
```

Using [`ndb.get_multi`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions) will be more efficient.  You can use [AppStats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) to verify that.  You might also look into the async equivalent if you have other processing you can do while the RPCs are outstanding.

I am not sure what the `Video.GetById` method actually is, but I would suggest you see the ndb documentation on [`Model.get_by_id`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everything is OK with your code. Does something go wrong with it?

Comment: it works, but it seems like there are a lot of steps to working with search. I was hoping I was doing it wrong. For example, is there a way to get from the scored documents to the entities directly? Iterating through a set of results twice doesn't seem like the ideal solution.

Comment: Current version of Search API [doesn't have](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/fieldclasses) something like KeyField, so you firstly have to create a key with ndb.Key(Video,doc_id) and then use it's get() method or use Video.get_by_id(doc_id) method as you did.

If you don't like to iterate twice you can do videos = [Video.get_by_id(x.doc_id) for x in video_search_docs].

Or, as Robert mentioned above, use ndb.get_multi(keys) instead as more efficient way.

Comment: Ahh, thanks Denisigo. That's probably what I was looking for I think. Other than reading the source, are there any guides on how the Search API is actually implemented? I'd be interested to know why something like `KeyField` doesn't exist?

Comment: Hmm... I can't say nothing about any other guides. By the way, Search API is marked as Experimental, so everything can happen, including addition of KeyField.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing where it goes. Is the App Engine Google Group the best place to follow/get involved in the discussion? #appengine on Freenode is not super active.

Comment: Yes. Google groups and stackoverflow is the most active places.